# Check whether an HTML input has been completed

Tags: javascript, html, css, local-storage

I am trying to program a login / register system with LocalStorage, HTML and Javascript. Now I want to check whether an HTML input element has been filled in or whether it is OK. I have not found a suitable post for this. Can someone help me?

HTML code:

```
<input id="register-input1" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" placeholder="Given name" name="ri1">
<input id="register-input2" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" placeholder="Surname" name="ri2">
<input id="register-input3" name="ri5" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" placeholder="E-Mail address">
<input id="register-input4" type="password" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" placeholder="Password" name="ri3">
<input id="register-input5" type="password" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" placeholder="Repeat Password" name="ri4">
```

Javascript Code:

```
var givenname = document.getElementById('register-input1');
var surname = document.getElementById('register-input2');
var email = document.getElementById('register-input3');
var password = document.getElementById('register-input4');
var password2 = document.getElementById('register-input5');

function storeRegisterData() {
  localStorage.setItem('givenname', givenname.value);
  localStorage.setItem('surname', surname.value);
  localStorage.setItem('email', email.value);
}

function checkRegisterData() {
  if(password.value !== password2.value) {
    alert('The first password does not match the second!')
  }else{
    --The review should be here!--
  }
}
```

(Translated with Google translated, errors could be included!)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
<input type="text" required>
```

or

you can simply use javascript :

```
function checkRegisterData() {
if(password.value !== password2.value) {
alert('The first password does not match the second!')
}else
 {
  if(givenname.value == NULL)
  {
   alert("Name field Empty");
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `required` attribute to make sure that the input feild is filled.
You can also use `min-length` and `max-length` to make sure that the length of the input matches the required length that you would like to be entered.

Example:

```
<input type="text" required="required" min-length="4" max-length="4923" />
```

(here the user must type in some text between 4 and 4923 characters long)